# Error connecting to team foundation server : failed to execute runnable(java.lang.noclassdeffounderror:org/slf4j/loggerfactory)

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tfs

While connecting the team foundation server from eclipse I'm facing the bellow mentioned error:

**Error connecting to server : failed to execute runnable(java.lang.noclassdeffounderror:org/slf4j/loggerfactory)**

Installed the **TFSEclipsePlugin** to eclipse(Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2))

From Team explorer selected **Connect to team services or team foundation server**

Inside **Add team foundation server** after entering the team server url facing the above mentioned error.
Same server able access from windows machine visual studio.

JDK version : jdk-8u281-macosx-x64

Mac OS : 12.2

Tried in other eclipse Neon 3.0 with same error

Please let me know if anyone has any solution or hint for the same.
Thanks

[There are many reported threads pointing to the same error but those are mostly while building the eclipse project not while connecting to the TFS  ]

[image]

Comment: Able to solve this issue: 1)Eclipse->Preference->Team->TeamFoundationServer->Accept untrusted SSL certificates.->select 2) Uninstalled ifs plugin and re installed by downloading from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/java/download-eclipse-plug-in?view=azure-devops
-> Download page for TEE 2015

Comment: Download link : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47727